# Can't connect react.js login to SpringBoot app

Tags: reactjs, spring-mvc

I am trying to call REST endpoints on one application (spring-boot) from another (reactjs). The applications are running on the following hosts and ports.

- REST application, using spring boot, http://localhost:8080
- HTML application, using reactjs, http://localhost:9000

I am trying to send the login info from reactjs to spring-boot but without success.

Reactjs:

```
import React from 'react';


export default class Login extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        login:"",
        password:""
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

}

handleChange() {
    this.setState({login: this.state.login});
}


render() {

    return (
        <form role="form">
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="login" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <input type="password" name="password"/>
            </div>
            <button onClick={this.login.bind(this)}>Login</button>
        </form>
    );
}


login () {


    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/test/login"
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url );
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({login: this.state.login}));
}
}
```

and Spring-boot:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000")
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/login")
public Boolean testLogin(@RequestParam String login) {
    if ( login.equals ("ajt"))

    return true;
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I can see that the two apps are connecting for even though reactjs gives me error 400, when I submit, the console of the Spring-boot app tells me:

```
 Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'login' is not present
```

I can only assume that from the Spring-boot side, it cannot translate what ever is sent via react.js.

ps: bear with me, I have been coding for about 6 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew this looked familiar.  Sorry my last answer didn't fix all your issues.

Your current problem is here;

```
public Boolean testLogin(@RequestParam String login) {
```

Should be

```
public Boolean testLogin(@RequestBody String login) {
```

EDIT::  Second problem.

Your `handleChange` function isn't taking in any values! It should look more like this;

```
handleChange(value) {
    this.setState({login: value});
}
```

When your input field calls this function, it needs to pass a value from the input *into* the state.  Your current code is essentially the same as this;

```
this.state.login = this.state.login;
```

Which obviously isn't going to get you anywhere.

Try that change.  If it still does not work, be sure you open your dev-tools in your browser and step through the code line by line to be sure it is executing and storing the values you want it to.

Comment: hehe, I just commented on the last one again :)

Comment: I posted this new question as I felt that it was not well formulated. Figured it might attract more interest. I have already tested this method and get the following error: 
`Required request body is missing: public java.lang.Boolean com.common.web.TestController.testLogin(java.lang.String)`

Comment: Ah, I see the issue.  Your `setState` isn't working properly, so your state never gets the login data in the first place.  As a general rule, get comfortable debugging in your console and verifying that the value of variables is what you expect.  If you pause the code during the `login` function and test the value of `this.state.login`, you'll see that it's undefined.  I'll update my answer to give more details though...

Comment: Thanks, so it is working now. Here were my mistakes. I was unaware that my server had to have a requestmethod.POST and .GET (the friend who is teaching me told me off :)) Also you were right about the state. I was spending time in the console but have yet to master it. I have also learned how to use breakpoints in Intellj which is a huge boost. Thanks, you've helped me a great deal, I learned a lot!